# Why class object sent to POST is coming NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have this POST method in api controller.

```
public void Post(EngineeringData EngineeringData)
{
    EngineeringDataDAL EngDataDAL = new EngineeringDataDAL();

    EngDataDAL.InsertEngineeringData(EngineeringData);
}
```

I am sending it a test data using POSTMAN.

```
 EngineeringData = {
    'FunctionalLocation': 'Functional1',
    'WINFileNo': 'WinFileNo-01',
    'EqptType': 'EqptType-01',
    'ComponentTagNo': 'Componenttag-01'
}
```

but the method's parameter is `null`. Why?

EngineeringData.cs

```
public class EngineeringData
{
    public int EnggDataID { get; set; }
    public string FunctionalLocation { get; set; }
    public string WinFileNo { get; set; }
    public string EqptType { get; set; }
    public string ComponentTagNo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes sir taht;s true

Comment: On problem is WinFileNo fields don't match.  One is "WINFileNo" the other is "WinFileNo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're including `EngineeringData=` in your request, that could be the reason. To the best of my knowledge, ASP.Net expects the body to be plain JSON, not form data.

Answer (score 3):

> I have this POST method in api controller.

```
 public void Post(EngineeringData EngineeringData)
```

What you are probably missing is

```
 public void Post([FromBody] EngineeringData EngineeringData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
    "FunctionalLocation": "Functional1",
    "WINFileNo": "WinFileNo-01",
    "EqptType": "EqptType-01",
    "ComponentTagNo": "Componenttag-01"
}
```

Try passing in this data. I believe it has to be valid JSON data to be passed to the controller to accept the parameters. Also not sure if the left parameter before the = sign is needed.